# Block level elements overlaying eachother

Tags: html, css, display

With some help I put together the "about_us" section in the following code and it functions exactly as I want it to (ignore the misbehaving text, works fine in the full project). The problem I have is that any object I try to place below the "about_us" section places itself below the first row only, rather than the whole block.

I've given each section a "block" description which, as far as I know, should put them one below the other, leading me to believe I've got something wrong rather than missed something out. Hopefully you can help me identify it. Thanks

```css
.about_us {
 max-width: 1600px;
 min-width: 800px;
 height: 370px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
}
.about_us_container {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 370px;
}
.about_us_image_clip, .about_us_background {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 50%;
 height: 370px;
 max-height: 370px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.about_us_img1 {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center !important;
 background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/2000);
 background-size: cover;
}
.about_us_img2 {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center !important;
 background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/2000);
 background-size: cover;
}
.about_us_img3 {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center !important;
 background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/2000);
 background-size: cover;
}
.about_us_heading {
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: "alexa-std";
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: 4% 4% 0%;
 color: floralwhite;
}
.about_us_description {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: alice;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: 2% 6%;
 text-indent: 40px;
 color: floralwhite;
}
.centre {
 display: block;
 max-width: 1600px;
 margin: auto;
}
.centre img {
 max-width: 1000px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="about_us">
 <div class="about_us_container">
  <div class="about_us_image_clip about_us_img1"></div>
  <div class="about_us_background" style="background-color: #63925C"><p class="about_us_heading">Heading One</p><p class="about_us_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla luctus, dolor in ultricies accumsan, sapien ligula faucibus orci, sed ullamcorper massa libero hendrerit elit. Proin egestas ac augue vitae dapibus. Phasellus quis magna arcu. Curabitur suscipit nulla sit amet leo rutrum, ac bibendum eros gravida. Nunc consectetur elit et est pretium fringilla. Maecenas sed imperdiet orci. Duis bibendum a erat nec dignissim. Aliquam eu libero sit amet nisi ultrices eleifend. Quisque auctor lectus non mi blandit sagittis. Nam gravida mauris augue, sed elementum nulla laoreet facilisis. Ut eleifend bibendum neque et mattis. Vivamus consequat iaculis malesuada. Integer sed aliquet mi.</p></div>
 </div>
 <div class="about_us_container">
  <div class="about_us_background" style="background-color: #6A8374"><p class="about_us_heading">Heading Two</p><p class="about_us_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla luctus, dolor in ultricies accumsan, sapien ligula faucibus orci, sed ullamcorper massa libero hendrerit elit. Proin egestas ac augue vitae dapibus. Phasellus quis magna arcu. Curabitur suscipit nulla sit amet leo rutrum, ac bibendum eros gravida. Nunc consectetur elit et est pretium fringilla. Maecenas sed imperdiet orci. Duis bibendum a erat nec dignissim. Aliquam eu libero sit amet nisi ultrices eleifend. Quisque auctor lectus non mi blandit sagittis. Nam gravida mauris augue, sed elementum nulla laoreet facilisis. Ut eleifend bibendum neque et mattis. Vivamus consequat iaculis malesuada. Integer sed aliquet mi.</p></div>
  <div class="about_us_image_clip about_us_img2"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="about_us_container">
  <div class="about_us_image_clip about_us_img3"></div>
  <div class="about_us_background" style="background-color: #63925C"><p class="about_us_heading">Heading Three</p><p class="about_us_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla luctus, dolor in ultricies accumsan, sapien ligula faucibus orci, sed ullamcorper massa libero hendrerit elit. Proin egestas ac augue vitae dapibus. Phasellus quis magna arcu. Curabitur suscipit nulla sit amet leo rutrum, ac bibendum eros gravida. Nunc consectetur elit et est pretium fringilla. Maecenas sed imperdiet orci. Duis bibendum a erat nec dignissim. Aliquam eu libero sit amet nisi ultrices eleifend. Quisque auctor lectus non mi blandit sagittis. Nam gravida mauris augue, sed elementum nulla laoreet facilisis. Ut eleifend bibendum neque et mattis. Vivamus consequat iaculis malesuada. Integer sed aliquet mi.</p></div>
 </div>
</section>
<section class="centre">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/500" width="1000" height="500" alt=""/> 
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your height settings for the classes .about_us and about_us_container were forcing the images to overlap. I just removed these and the results should be closer to what you had in mind.

```css
.about_us {
  max-width: 1600px;
  min-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.about_us_container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.about_us_image_clip,
.about_us_background {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  height: 370px;
  max-height: 370px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.about_us_img1 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center !important;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/2000);
  background-size: cover;
}

.about_us_img2 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center !important;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/2000);
  background-size: cover;
}

.about_us_img3 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center !important;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/2000);
  background-size: cover;
}

.about_us_heading {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "alexa-std";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 4% 4% 0%;
  color: floralwhite;
}

.about_us_description {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: alice;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 2% 6%;
  text-indent: 40px;
  color: floralwhite;
}

.centre {
  display: block;
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.centre img {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="about_us">
  <div class="about_us_container">
    <div class="about_us_image_clip about_us_img1"></div>
    <div class="about_us_background" style="background-color: #63925C">
      <p class="about_us_heading">Heading One</p>
      <p class="about_us_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla luctus, dolor in ultricies accumsan, sapien ligula faucibus orci, sed ullamcorper massa libero hendrerit elit. Proin egestas ac augue vitae dapibus. Phasellus quis magna arcu. Curabitur
        suscipit nulla sit amet leo rutrum, ac bibendum eros gravida. Nunc consectetur elit et est pretium fringilla. Maecenas sed imperdiet orci. Duis bibendum a erat nec dignissim. Aliquam eu libero sit amet nisi ultrices eleifend. Quisque auctor lectus
        non mi blandit sagittis. Nam gravida mauris augue, sed elementum nulla laoreet facilisis. Ut eleifend bibendum neque et mattis. Vivamus consequat iaculis malesuada. Integer sed aliquet mi.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about_us_container">
    <div class="about_us_background" style="background-color: #6A8374">
      <p class="about_us_heading">Heading Two</p>
      <p class="about_us_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla luctus, dolor in ultricies accumsan, sapien ligula faucibus orci, sed ullamcorper massa libero hendrerit elit. Proin egestas ac augue vitae dapibus. Phasellus quis magna arcu. Curabitur
        suscipit nulla sit amet leo rutrum, ac bibendum eros gravida. Nunc consectetur elit et est pretium fringilla. Maecenas sed imperdiet orci. Duis bibendum a erat nec dignissim. Aliquam eu libero sit amet nisi ultrices eleifend. Quisque auctor lectus
        non mi blandit sagittis. Nam gravida mauris augue, sed elementum nulla laoreet facilisis. Ut eleifend bibendum neque et mattis. Vivamus consequat iaculis malesuada. Integer sed aliquet mi.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="about_us_image_clip about_us_img2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="about_us_container">
    <div class="about_us_image_clip about_us_img3"></div>
    <div class="about_us_background" style="background-color: #63925C">
      <p class="about_us_heading">Heading Three</p>
      <p class="about_us_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla luctus, dolor in ultricies accumsan, sapien ligula faucibus orci, sed ullamcorper massa libero hendrerit elit. Proin egestas ac augue vitae dapibus. Phasellus quis magna arcu. Curabitur
        suscipit nulla sit amet leo rutrum, ac bibendum eros gravida. Nunc consectetur elit et est pretium fringilla. Maecenas sed imperdiet orci. Duis bibendum a erat nec dignissim. Aliquam eu libero sit amet nisi ultrices eleifend. Quisque auctor lectus
        non mi blandit sagittis. Nam gravida mauris augue, sed elementum nulla laoreet facilisis. Ut eleifend bibendum neque et mattis. Vivamus consequat iaculis malesuada. Integer sed aliquet mi.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="centre">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/500" width="1000" height="500" alt="" />
</section>
```